# Significant support of non-central chi-quared distribution

Tags: distributions, non-central, chi-squared-distribution, highest-density-region

I want to find the support of a non-central chi-squared distribution ($99.9 \%$ of the energy). For example, If I have a Gaussian distribution with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$, I know $99.9 \%$ of the energy is in $[\mu - 3\sigma, \mu + 3\sigma]$. How can I find a similar support for non-central chi-squared distribution with degrees of freedom $\nu$ and non-centrality parameter $\lambda$?

Comment: By "energy" do you mean "probability"?  Assuming that's the case, could you tell us how you computed the answer for the Gaussian distribution--and then explain why the same method would not work for a non-central $\chi^2$ distribution?

Comment: For Gaussian distribution, I did not compute the answer but it is known (see tables in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution  for F(μ + nσ) − F(μ − nσ) for different n).

Answer (score 2):

You do it the same way you could do it for a normal distribution, by using the cdf (cumulative distribution function) $F$ or better, its inverse, the quantile function $Q=F^{-1}$. There is only one complication, the normal distribution is unimodal and symmetric, so it is quite clear that the shortest interval containing a given probability $p$ is the central interval (around the symmetry point) given by $(Q(p/2), Q(1-p/2))$ (assuming $p>1/2$.)

The non-central chi-squared is *not* symmetric, so the equal-tail interval given above will not be the shortest one (the shortest one will be the HPD interval [Proof that the HPD region is the smallest](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311995/proof-that-the-hpd-region-is-the-smallest).  As an example for the noncentral chisquare, in R, the equal-tail interval is

```
qchisq(c(0.005, 0.995), df=10, ncp=1)
[1]  2.380353 27.588429
```

while the HPD interval will be more work, but there is a dedicated R package:

```
 HDInterval::hdi(function(p)qchisq(p, df=10, ncp=1), 0.99)
    lower     upper 
 1.660555 25.793967 
attr(,"credMass")
[1] 0.99
```

which must be using numerical optimization.

Answer (score 1):

HDRs for standard probability distributions can also be computed using the [`stat.extend`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stat.extend/index.html)package.  This gives a user friendly output for the region in set form.  Here is an example of computing the region for a particular choice of parameters.

```
#Compute and print HDR for the chi-squared distribution
DF  <- 10
NCP <- 1
HDR <- stat.extend::HDR.chisq(0.99, df = DF, ncp = NCP)
HDR

        Highest Density Region (HDR) 
 
99.00% HDR for chi-squared distribution with 10 degrees-of-freedom and 
non-centrality parameter = 1
Computed using nlm optimisation with 8 iterations (code = 1) 

[1.66055476349383, 25.7939667370053]
```

It can easily be established that the endpoints of the interval have the same density value (to within a small tolerance from the optimisation algorithm) and that the interval has the required coverage level.

```
#Check endpoints of HDR
dchisq(min(HDR), df = DF, ncp = NCP)
[1] 0.002842709

dchisq(max(HDR), df = DF, ncp = NCP)
[1] 0.002842709

#Check coverage probability
pchisq(max(HDR), df = DF, ncp = NCP) - pchisq(min(HDR), df = DF, ncp = NCP)
[1] 0.99
```