# Proof that the HPD region is the smallest

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, credible-interval

In one dimension it can be shown that the highest posterior density (HPD) interval is the shortest; I found a proof in *Subjective and Objective Bayesian Statistics* ([Section 8.4](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=eJO1abQ4l3wC&lpg=PA211&dq=highest%20posterior%20density%20shortest%20interval%20on%20a%20posterior%20density%20proof&pg=PA211#v=onepage&q&f=false)) by S. James Press where a suitable Lagrangian is built and used to find the solution.

Does anyone know of a proof for the higher dimensional case?

Comment: The proof is the same: take a subset out of the HPD and you need more volume to achieve the same coverage.

Comment: @Xi'an thanks! in the 1-d case, is your suggestion equivalent to the proof above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in comments:

The proof is the same: take a subset out of the HPD and you need more volume to achieve the same coverage. – Xi'an